# The animation not running in WPF 3D

Tags: wpf, animation, 3d, transformation

Can someone help me to find out why this does not work:

```
var story = new Storyboard {Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)};

var meshBuilder = new MeshBuilder();
meshBuilder.AddCone(new Point3D(0, 0, 0), new Vector3D(0, 0, 1), 15, 10, 50, false, false, 20);

var mesh = meshBuilder.ToMesh();
var geometryModel = new GeometryModel3D
{
    Geometry = mesh,
    Material = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DeepSkyBlue)),
    BackMaterial = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue)),
};
var modelVisual = new ModelVisual3D { Content = geometryModel };
helixViewport.Children.Add(modelVisual);

var scaleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
{
    BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
    From = 1,
    To = 2,
    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
};
var scaleTransform3D = new ScaleTransform3D(1, 1, 2);

var transform3DGroup = new Transform3DGroup();
transform3DGroup.Children.Add(scaleTransform3D);

modelVisual.Transform = transform3DGroup;

story.Children.Add(scaleAnimation);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(scaleAnimation, new PropertyPath(ScaleTransform3D.ScaleZProperty));
Storyboard.SetTarget(scaleAnimation, modelVisual);

story.Begin();
```

First of all I just create a cone by using HelixToolkit, after that I want to scale it. The animation will last 10 seconds and start from second 1 and last 10 seconds.   But the animation is not executed, the viewport only displayed the final result after scaling.   **NOTE**: this is the simplify part of a whole code, real code will have multiple animation applied to multiple model and each will start at different time. That is why I want to use storyboard and BeginTime here.  Please help me find out what I did wrong.

Comment: Thank for Clemens's help, it is working now: only 2 lines need to change:    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(scaleAnimation, new PropertyPath("Transform.Children[0].ScaleZ"));  and            var scaleTransform3D = new ScaleTransform3D(1, 1, 1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to animate the `ScaleTransform3D.ScaleZProperty` on an object of type `ModelVisual3D`, which does not have that property. You should change the

```
var path = "Transform.Children[0].ScaleZ";
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(scaleAnimation, new PropertyPath(path));
Storyboard.SetTarget(scaleAnimation, modelVisual);
```

You might also simplify your code by omitting the Storyboard. Just call

```
scaleTransform3D.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform3D.ScaleZProperty, scaleAnimation)
```

Also, you should initialize `scaleTransform3D` with a `ScaleZ` value of 1, since you want to animate `ScaleZ` from 1 to 2.

```
var scaleTransform3D = new ScaleTransform3D(1, 1, 1);
```

or by the default constructor, since all scale values default to 1.

```
var scaleTransform3D = new ScaleTransform3D();
```

Comment: Hi Clemens, I try to use    Storyboard.SetTarget(scaleAnimation, scaleTransform3D); but it is not working.  And I did try     scaleTransform3D.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform3D.ScaleZProperty, scaleAnimation) before I make this post but the animation start right away, not from the BeginTime that I setup

Comment: Yes, Storyboard may not work as the animation target is not a FrameworkElement. See my edit, I've changed the property path instead of the animation target now. Although it's still not a FrameworkElement. Well, I'm not sure about this. Could you double-check the `BeginAnimation` solution?

Comment: Hi Clemens, your code throw exception, but from that I change to    Storyboard.SetTarget(scaleAnimation, modelVisual);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(scaleAnimation, new PropertyPath("Transform.Children[0].ScaleZ"));  and the animation start. But another strange problem arise: first the result after scaling appear, after that, at the BeginTime, the animation start. Why did it happen?

Comment: Sorry, i can't tell. Actually i've never used all this 3D stuff, just plain 2D transforms and visuals. What happens if you omit the `From = 1` from the animation declaration?

Comment: If I omit    From = 1, animation will not run, it needs From and To value to know where to start

Comment: No, if you don't set From, it starts from the current value. I guess that's what you want.

Comment: I do not understand either, in my case when I remove From = 1; animation do not run. Now only thing I do not understand is: why the result after before the animation start?

Comment: See Remarks in [DoubleAnimation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation.from.aspx) about how `From`, `To` and `By` may be used together. And I realized that you initialize the transform by `new ScaleTransform3D(1, 1, 2)`, meaning that `ScaleZ` is already 2. Now you animate from 1 to 2, is that really what you want? You should perhaps start with `new ScaleTransform3D(1, 1, 1)`.

Comment: You are right, I need to start with    new ScaleTransform3D(1, 1, 1). Thank a lot for your help.

Comment: It's also worth to mention the animation's [FillBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior.aspx) property here. It is `HoldEnd` by default, which causes the ScaleZ property to stay at a value of 2 until it is set to another value. Without that it would flip back to the base value (the non-animated value) of 1 after the animation has ended.